# How to fix the "Some settings are managed by your organization" message

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, group-policy

I get constantly the annoying message:

```
Some settings are managed by your organization
```

[image]

I have tried everything to remove it, for example:

- Editing the `gpedit.msc` file
- Running `sc config` commands
- Trying to edit the *registry* manually from the command `regedit`

I am using a *Windows 10 Enterprise x86 (32 bit), running the 1511 build: 10586.104*.

How can I remove it?

Comment: We arn't a traditional forum. Imagine this is jeopardy, and try framing your question as a question *as you would ask someone else* and posting  an answer seperately. http://superuser.com/help/self-answer is an awesome starting point. I'm putting it on hold for now, but you really ought to flag for mod attention once you have this fixed up

Comment: Well I cannot answer or reply to other peoples questions so I made a question with how I solved the same problem so they can find it and fix it on their computers... This 10 reputation thing is not cool. If we have a solution, we should be able to jump right on and tell others how we solved the same issue they are having.

Comment: @RandomUsername - You can post a question then post an answer.  If you have submitted answers in the past, and have been bared from submitting answers, that something else entirely.

Comment: Is your computer part of a domain?

Answer (score 2):

This message means that you are in a company domain.

Administrators of your domain have automatically centralized the configuration of the machines in the domain by using GPO or GPP.

The goal can be :

- to standardize the behavior of all the computers in the domain
- to improve the security by disabling some functionalities not useful for work
- ...

If you need to access those options, you will have to ask your company IT service which manage the Active Directory rules to enable those options for you.

Comment: That is only one possibility. Group Policies can also be defined locally.

Comment: You are right. It can be set by launching secpol.msc

Answer (score -1):

Solution:

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

Type: regedit (press <kbd>Enter</kbd>) and Click Yes when prompted.

Goto:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE → SOFTWARE → POLICIES → MICROSOFT → WINDOWS → PERSONALIZATION

(if it doesn't exist, create it)

Inside PERSONALIZATION, create a New DWORD (32-bit Value) name it: `NoLockScreen` with a value of `0` (zero) hex.

If you already do have `NoLockScreen` and the value is *1* change te value to "0".

Comment: He didn't indicate where the message appears, so a local solution isn't going to help.

Comment: @DanielB Added an image to show where the message appears.

Comment: ? This is but one possibility. This message appears wherever Group Policies apply. That means it can appear almost anywhere in both the legacy and Metro control panels. Unless the OP himself adds more information, especially on domain membership, this question cannot be answered.