# Windows 10: "Some settings are managed by your organization": MDM managing Windows settings as organization, but origin unknown

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, group-policy

I keep getting this message *Some settings are managed by your organization* in my Windows settings. I am **not** domain joined and there are **no** provisioning packages. **I want to get rid of the message and let me control my own computer again.**

[image: 'Some settings are managed by your organization.']

I recently found that most of the unchangeable settings are caused by a policy called *Mobile Device Management*, since this is what the Windows Update screen in the settings is telling me.

[image: Windows Update telling MDM manages my organization settings]
<sup>**Set policies on your device**</sup>

The weird thing is that there is no school or other organization connected to my local Windows account at this moment. There used to be, but I already removed it a few months ago. Here are two screenshots of my school/work settings on my PC :

Settings -> Accounts -> Access work or school:

[image: School settings]

Settings -> Accounts -> Access work or school -> Add or remove a provisioning package:

[image: Provisioning package settings]

I thought that it would be a provisioning package that would cause the settings being "managed by the organization", however there is no provisioning package, and no option to add one either (the plus icon is grayed out). The %ProgramData%\Microsoft\Provisioning folder is empty.

Does anyone have an idea how to get rid of this message and let me control my own computer again?

Note: I already tried the following:

- ["Some settings are managed by your organization" while not on domain?](https://superuser.com/questions/947755/some-settings-are-managed-by-your-organization-while-not-on-domain)
- [Can't enable Windows Hello - Some settings are managed by your organization](https://superuser.com/questions/1113638/cant-enable-windows-hello-some-settings-are-managed-by-your-organization?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [How to fix the "Some settings are managed by your organization" message](https://superuser.com/questions/1044022/how-to-fix-the-some-settings-are-managed-by-your-organization-message?rq=1)
- [Windows 10 “Some settings are managed by your organization” (gpedit.msc does not work)](https://superuser.com/questions/1160213/windows-10-some-settings-are-managed-by-your-organization-gpedit-msc-does-not?rq=1)
- [Windows update - some settings are managed by your organization](https://superuser.com/questions/1340271/windows-update-some-settings-are-managed-by-your-organization?rq=1)
- ["some of these settings are hidden or managed by your organization" Start Menu Settings](https://superuser.com/questions/1507095/some-of-these-settings-are-hidden-or-managed-by-your-organization-start-menu-s?rq=1)

Notice that for changing the diagnostics option in my settings, the option to send "Enhanced" diagnostics is grayed out. I can only send "Basic" diagnostics (currently selected). Changing this in the Group Policy editor does not change a thing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Question and especially screenshots are expected to be in English

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/947755/some-settings-are-managed-by-your-organization-while-not-on-domain and https://superuser.com/questions/1113638/cant-enable-windows-hello-some-settings-are-managed-by-your-organization

Comment: @Ramhound I edited my question for clarity. I hope that it is clear now that the linked questions are not duplicates and that this is a new case. My Windows installation is in Dutch so it is not possible for me to give you English screenshots, but I added the location of the settings screen.

Comment: Try disconnecting your Microsoft account from the profile

Comment: I disconnected my Microsoft account yesterday, with no changes to this problem.

Comment: Have you used any application that claims to disable Windows 10 "spying" features?

Comment: I did use O&O shutup. I recently revoked all changes made by the application to the default Windows settings and restarted my pc, without any effect.

Comment: Those privacy hacks are known to make changes that cannot be reversed.  Sadly, the only way I know to solve your problem at this point, is to perform an in-place upgrade to the same version you are already running.

Answer (score -1):

Likely any changes made by the organization MDM (a system of controlling and securing remote devices and workers) are still sticking around. The only true solution is to reinstall a clean copy of Windows to refresh the policies. Try using the Windows USB install method to repair it.

Alternatively, Try using a System File Check through CMD or Powershell. Here is the link to the install media:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/15088/windows-10-create-installation-media

You could also attempt a 'refresh' from the settings page, which will keep the majority of your stuff, but will remove installed apps.

Search 'reset this PC' (reset deze pc?) from the start menu, and go through the process there.

If all of these fail to work, let me know.